# Exportar output de python a csv

Tags: python, pandas

Necesito que el output de este fragmento python se exporte como un archivo tipo .csv
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```python
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

rciudades=pd.read_csv('ciudades.csv')
rpersonajes=pd.read_csv('personajes.csv')
rtodo=glob.glob("./*.csv")
rtodito=pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in rtodo))

print(pd.merge(rciudades, rpersonajes, on='telefono', how="left"))
```

Comment: En la [documentación](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) de pandas dice como. Además, te agradecería mucho que aceptases la respuesta que te di en tu pregunta anterior (ya que parece que te sirvió).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has probado con `dataFrame.to_csv`?

```
df=pd.merge(rciudades, rpersonajes, on='telefono', how="left")
df.to_csv('salida.csv')
```